# gcloud logs read not showing data access logs programmatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to fetch data access logs for Cloud Profiler API which is created using VM Instance. I can see profile is created successfully in Logs Explorer and logName contains data_access.

Now, I am trying to fetch those logs programmatically. I tried through Cloud Function entries.list API. Number of ways I have tried, I am not getting any error but no logs are showing, all other logs except for Data_Acess logs are visible, just when i filter through data access logs output is nothing, but when i do the same in Console, its there

Same way I tried with gcloud logging read command, still nothing output i am getting.

```
gcloud beta logging read 'timestamp>="2021-05-13T12:09:05Z" AND logName:"projects/******/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"' --limit=10 --format=json --order=asc
```

I have tried changing the order to desc, different filters I have tried but not working

I am getting proper response from Google API Explorer

**Update** I got it working after re-authentication but still my cloud function doesn't work. How would i re-authenticate in Cloud Function

```
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer "+ credentials.token}
r = requests.post("https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list", params=payload, headers=headers)
```

this is how i am running my code in Cloud Function. As a output with same parameters as in gcloud, i am getting {}

Comment: I have no issue on my side. Are you sure of your parameters? what is your OS?

Comment: I am running these commands on GCP VM Instance debian, I got it working by just re-authenticating, but how would i re-authenticate i Cloud Function

Comment: How can you say that your cloud function isn't authenticated? Did you get a 401 or 403? how do you generate the token?

Answer (score 0):

Are you an owner or an editor?  I recently saw this issue with a team member where I could see the data logs but he could not.  He could see them after his role was changed from editor to owner.